# Django : How to annotate, group by user and annotate again using the first annotation?

Tags: django

I  a Django (1.11) project with a ReadingSession model as follows:

```
class ReadingSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)        
    started_at = models.DateTimeField()
    ended_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I want to display the sum of the reading sessions durations for each of some given users, in one database request.

Among other attempts, I've tried :

```
usernames = ['user1', 'user2',] 
q = ReadingSession.objects.filter(user__username__in=usernames)\
    .annotate(duration=Func(F('ended_at'), F('started_at'), function='age'))\
    .order_by().values('user') \
    .annotate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))\
    .values('user', 'total_duration')
print q
```

but it fails with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File ".../misc_queries.py", line 74, in <module>
test_query()
 File ".../misc_queries.py", line 51, in test_query
.annotate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))
 File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 945, in annotate
clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
 File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 973, in add_annotation
summarize=is_summary)
 File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 19, in resolve_expression
c = super(Aggregate, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 548, in resolve_expression
c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 471, in resolve_expression
return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
File "..../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1472, in resolve_ref
  return self.annotation_select[name]
KeyError: 'duration'
```

Which makes sense, as the "values('user')" statement  filtered the fields returned by the 'filter()' statement.
But on the other side, if I add 'duration' in the first 'values()' statement, the results are not groupped by user anymore.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong here or have you another way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do it as a complex db query, but how about returning the data and iterating over it in the view?

```
queryset = ReadingSession.objects.all()

results = {}
for record in queryset:
    if not record.user in results:
        results[record.user] = timedelta(microseconds=0)
    time_diff = record.ended_at - record.started_at
    results[record.user] += time_diff

return results
```

That will return a dictionary of results[username] = [sum of session times]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this is an option I have considered but I was thinking Django ORM would offer a more efficient way to deal with this use case

Comment: Beyond performance, the problem with this approach is you can't sort, filter, and combine using standard queryset operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Window functions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

```py
from django.db import models

usernames = ('user1', 'user2',)

q = ReadingSession.objects.filter(
    user__username__in=usernames
).annotate(
    duration=models.Func(models.F('ended_at'), models.F('started_at'), function='age')
).annotate(
    total_duration=models.Window(
        expression=models.Sum('duration'),
        partition_by=[models.F('user')],
    )
).values('user', 'total_duration')

print q
```